# How to re-enable Orchard CMS features without Dashboard or command line

Tags: orchardcms

I just disabled the Comments feature on my Orchard installation, not realising it was a dependency of Disqus, and now the entire site including admin dashboard fails with this error:

*None of the constructors found with policy 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'Disqus.Comments.Services.DisqusCommentUpdateService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.IOrchardServices, Disqus.Comments.Services.IDisqusMappingService, Orchard.Comments.Services.ICommentService)' parameter resolution failed at parameter 'Orchard.Comments.Services.ICommentService commentService'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with policy 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'Disqus.Comments.Services.DisqusCommentUpdateService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Constructor 'Void .ctor(Orchard.IOrchardServices, Disqus.Comments.Services.IDisqusMappingService, Orchard.Comments.Services.ICommentService)' parameter resolution failed at parameter 'Orchard.Comments.Services.ICommentService commentService'.*

The Orchard installation is running on a web host and I do not have access to the command line there.  I have FTP access, and access to the MS SQL database.  Is there any way I can re-enable the Comments feature without access to the command line or web admin interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a file, /orchard.web/app_data/cache.dat, which is an xml containing a list of which features are enabled.

The documentation warns that modifying it may have unpredictable results, so be warned: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Developer-FAQ#What'sinApp_Data?

Comment: Thanks - this eventually fixed it, after an app pool recycle.  It seems even if I modify the database as mdm suggested, the app still uses the cached values in cache.dat during startup, which is where it was failing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a table in the database called `Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord`, which stores the state for each module's feature. I re-enabled Orchard.Comments on my local installation (using SQL Server Compact Edition) with the following SQL:

```
update Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord
set InstallState = 'Up',
    EnableState = 'Up'
where Name = 'Orchard.Comments'
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks mdm...I tried it, and the site is still failing.  Did you have to do anything else to get it to work?  I've tried recycling the app pool and even stopping/starting the server altogether, to no avail :(

Comment: You could try deleting the `cache.dat` file in the sites folder which is basically a cache of that table's data. Delete this then restart IIS. You might also want to try using the SQL statement above to disable the Disqus module, although I'm not sure of the syntax off the top of my head (and I'm away from that machine now unfortunately).